# System.DBNULL casting problem in EF Core 6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

I have started learning asp .net and mysql for almost a month now and I have been building a web app for the company where I have been interning. In the final phase of the project, after implementing the last feature an error with the database connection started appearing, in a part of the code that I didn't touch for the last days. Every other single table in my database doesn't have a problem just this one. The strangest part is, I have the data in the data base, in the view before I show it, and then when trying to acess it again to get some the data it appears as empty. While trying to see the data of the table during debugging an error appears saying that an internal exception occured and that

> unable to cast 'System.DBNULL' to type 'System.String'.This is the class model for that table

```
public class Pdc_Ecra
       {
           [Key]
           public int PE_Id { get; set; }
           public string PE_Ativo { get; set; }
           public DateTime PE_Data_hora { get; set; }
           public int PE_Contador { get; set; }
           public int PE_Qtd_produzida { get; set; }
           public int PE_user_Id { get; set; }
           [ForeignKey("PE_user_Id")]
           public virtual User User { get; set; }
           public int PE_pdc_Id { get; set; }
           [ForeignKey("PE_pdc_Id")]
           public virtual Producao Producao { get; set; }
           public int PE_ecra_Id { get; set; }
           [ForeignKey("PE_ecra_Id")]
           public virtual Ecra Ecra { get; set; }
           public string PE_obs { get; set; }
       }
```

This is the table in the database

[Table rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4iJP.png)
[Table content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcO7H.png)

This is the controller where it cames from

```
public IActionResult Vecras(int? id, string referringView)
        {
            int id2;

            if (id == null)
            {
                id2 = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Vid"]);
                TempData["Vid"] = id2;
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Vid"] = id;
                id2 = id ?? default(int);
            }
            Producao producao = _db.producao
                .Include(p => p.Pdc_Ecras)
                    .ThenInclude(pe => pe.Ecra)
                        .ThenInclude(e => e.Tipo_Ecra)
                .Include(p => p.Pdc_Ecras)
                    .ThenInclude(pe => pe.Ecra)
                        .ThenInclude(e => e.Cor_Ecra)
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.pdc_Id == id2);


            if (producao == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var controlador = _db.producao_ecra.FirstOrDefault(e => e.PE_pdc_Id == id2);
            if (controlador == null)
            {
                foreach (var decoracao in producao.Decoracao.Ecras)
                {
                    var corEcraNome = decoracao.ecra_CE_Id;
                    var tipoEcraNome = decoracao.ecra_TE_Id;
                    var decID = decoracao.ecra_dec_Id;

                    var userId = GetName(Log2.log2_nome);
                    var existingEcra = _db.ecra.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ecra_Ativa == "S" && e.ecra_CE_Id == corEcraNome && e.ecra_TE_Id == tipoEcraNome && e.ecra_dec_Id == decID);
                    var ecraAtivar = _db.ecra.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ecra_Ativa == "N" && e.ecra_CE_Id == corEcraNome && e.ecra_TE_Id == tipoEcraNome && e.ecra_dec_Id == decID);
                    if (existingEcra == null)
                    {
                        var pdcEcra = new Pdc_Ecra
                        {
                            PE_pdc_Id = producao.pdc_Id,
                            PE_ecra_Id = decoracao.ecra_Id,
                            PE_Data_hora = DateTime.Now,
                            PE_Contador = 0,
                            PE_Ativo = "S",
                            PE_user_Id = userId,
                        };

                        _db.producao_ecra.Add(pdcEcra);
                        if (ecraAtivar != null)
                        {
                            ecraAtivar.ecra_Ativa = "S";
                        }

                        _db.SaveChanges();
                    }

                }
            }
            ViewBag.ReferringView = referringView;
              
            return View(producao);
        }
```

This is the controller that opens the view

```
public IActionResult Trocar(int id)
        {
            string ceNome = GetCor(id);
            string teNome = GetTipo(id);
            string decNumero = GetDec(id);
            int ecraID = GetID(id);
            TempData["IdPE"] = id;
            var ecras = _db.ecra
                .Join(_db.ecra,
                    b => b.ecra_Id,
                    e => e.ecra_Id,
                    (b, e) => new { Ecra1 = b, Ecra2 = e })
                .Join(_db.cor_ecra,
                    be => be.Ecra2.ecra_CE_Id,
                    c => c.CE_Id,
                    (be, c) => new { Ecra = be, Cor = c })
                .Join(_db.tipo_ecra,
                    bec => bec.Ecra.Ecra1.ecra_TE_Id,
                    t => t.TE_Id,
                    (bec, t) => new { EcraCor = bec, Tipo = t })
                .Join(_db.decoracao,
                    bect => bect.EcraCor.Ecra.Ecra1.ecra_dec_Id,
                    d => d.dec_Id,
                    (bect, d) => new {EcraCorTipo = bect, Decoracao = d })
                .Where(ecd => ecd.EcraCorTipo.EcraCor.Cor.CE_Nome == ceNome &&
                               ecd.EcraCorTipo.Tipo.TE_Nome == teNome &&
                               ecd.Decoracao.dec_Numero == int.Parse(decNumero) &&
                               ecd.EcraCorTipo.EcraCor.Ecra.Ecra1.ecra_Id != ecraID)
                .Select(ecd => ecd.EcraCorTipo.EcraCor.Ecra.Ecra1)
                .ToList();


            return View(ecras);
        }
```

The first time this problem appear is when calling the GetCor function, the id value is well received both in the Trocar and in GetCor

```
public string GetCor(int id)
        {
            var item = _db.producao_ecra.FirstOrDefault(t => t.PE_Id == id);


            if (item != null)
            {
                return item.Ecra.Cor_Ecra.CE_Nome.ToString();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

It happens right in the first line of code of GetCor.
All the others tables have been working fine, including this one before it starts this out of nowhere
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why are you using JOINs in LINQ? EF is an ORM, not a database driver. *It* generates the JOINs from the relations between objects, allowing you to work with entities (not tables) as if you were working with in-memory objects. If you have a `Blog` with a `Posts` property, EF will generate any JOINs needed to retrieve a blog's posts automatically. `Include` is used to eagerly load related objects that *aren't* already returned by any `Select` clause

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the 'PE_obs'-property of your Pdc_Ecra-class. Its supposed to be non-nullable (string .. instead of string? ..) but if you look at your table-contents you'll see its NULL in all rows. Also, within your code 'PE_obs' appears to never be set.
Two possible solutions:
either make the property nullable

```
public string? PE_obs { get; set; }
```

or manually replace all null-values in your table and make sure the field is allways set when creating or updating a record